# Replacement for sys/socket.h in linux kernel module?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, linux-kernel, kernel-module

There is a TPM 2.0 Simulator by IBM, that communicates over sockets. I have to connect to the locahost at a specific port and then send my commands over that connection.

I want to be able to use it as if I have a hardware TPM, though. So I thought I would write a kernel module, that provides a character device driver for this under `/dev/tpm0`.

It is basically a proxy, that sends all the commands it receives to the Simulator and relays the answers.

I would need `socket`s for this task and already successfully connected to the Simulator with a user mode application I wrote.

When transferring this to the driver I wrote, though, the make file complains, that `sys/socket.h` can not be found.

Through research I already heard, that some libraries can only be used in user mode and I assume that `sys/socket.h` is one of them.

So what is the kernel replacement for it? I read a lot of articles explaining how to configure a server in a kernel module, but nothing on a client.

Comment: No need to write a kernel module. You can use the `socat` command as described [here](http://serverfault.com/a/384756/166536) for example.

Comment: @hek2mgl Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: Can you check this. I believe you have some idea on this.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77196417/how-to-convert-net-conn-into-io-readwritecloser-golang

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

A sample tcp server runs in kernel:

https://gist.github.com/llj098/752417

Comment: I found this, too. But it is using the old `struct msghdr` interface. The `msg_iov` member is not used anymore in kernels > 3.19, I think.