# How to convert net.Conn into io.ReadWriteCloser Golang

Tags: go, tcp, tpm

I am trying to run this sample application,
https://github.com/salrashid123/tpm2/blob/master/sign_with_rsa/main.go

which uses /dev/tpm0 file which is available where the real tpm connected. This code works fine in an ubuntu host where I have real tpm 2.0 and tpm2-tools installed.

But I am trying to run the same application with tpm2.0 simulator installed in a VM. I have installed simulator from,
https://jaist.dl.sourceforge.net/project/ibmswtpm2/ibmtpm1661.tar.gz

it runs great and able to execute tpm commands like, tpm2_pcrread successfully. But not able to run the above sample application here.
if you look the below snippet from the sample application,

```
    rwc, err := tpm2.OpenTPM(*tpmPath)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Can't open TPM %s: %v", *tpmPath, err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
```

they get readwritecloser instance by opening the tpm file which is /dev/tpm0. for a simulator, there is no such file. It run as a server client socket.

```
 service tpm-server status
● tpm-server.service - TPM2.0 Simulator Server daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/tpm-server.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2023-09-28 13:52:23 IST; 7h ago
   Main PID: 14256 (tpm_server)
      Tasks: 3 (limit: 4594)
     Memory: 848.0K
     CGroup: /system.slice/tpm-server.service
             └─14256 /usr/local/bin/tpm_server

Sep 28 16:04:40  tpm_server[14256]: Command IPv4 client accepted
Sep 28 16:04:40  tpm_server[14256]: TPM command server listening on port 2321
Sep 28 16:07:57  tpm_server[14256]: Command IPv4 client accepted
Sep 28 16:07:57  tpm_server[14256]: Unrecognized TPM interface command 80020000
Sep 28 16:07:57  tpm_server[14256]: TPM command server listening on port 2321
Sep 28 16:25:39  tpm_server[14256]: Command IPv4 client accepted
Sep 28 16:25:39  tpm_server[14256]: Unrecognized TPM interface command 80020000
Sep 28 16:25:39  tpm_server[14256]: TPM command server listening on port 2321
Sep 28 16:31:33  tpm_server[14256]: Command IPv4 client accepted
Sep 28 16:31:33  tpm_server[14256]: **TPM command server listening on port 2321**
```

Server is listening on port 2321.

So I have tried modifying the above code piece into,

```
conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", "10.0.84.68:2321")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Error connecting to TPM simulator: %v", err)
}
defer conn.Close()

// Wrap the net.Conn in an io.ReadWriteCloser
//rwc := conn.(io.ReadWriteCloser)
rwc := io.ReadWriteCloser(conn)
```

I don't know this is a correct way of converting net.Conn into io.ReadWriteCloser.

while running the app, it throws below log,

```
./main 
Error creating Primary read tcp 10.0.84.68:50900->10.0.84.68:2321: read: connection reset by peer
```

server log shows,

```
Sep 28 16:07:57  tpm_server[14256]: TPM command server listening on port 2321
Sep 28 16:25:39  tpm_server[14256]: Command IPv4 client accepted
Sep 28 16:25:39  tpm_server[14256]:
```

> **Unrecognized TPM interface command 80020000**

```
Sep 28 16:25:39  tpm_server[14256]: TPM command server listening on port 2321
```

Below is the server side code where it throws the above error, (look at the switch case - default)

```
bool
TpmServer(
      SOCKET           s
      )
{
    uint32_t             length;
    uint32_t             Command;
    uint8_t              locality;
    bool                 OK;
    int                  result;
    int                  clientVersion;
    _IN_BUFFER           InBuffer;
    _OUT_BUFFER          OutBuffer;
    for(;;)
    {
        OK = ReadBytes(s, (char*)&Command, 4);
        // client disconnected (or other error).  We stop processing this client
        // and return to our caller who can stop the server or listen for another
        // connection.
        if(!OK)
        return true;
        Command = ntohl(Command);
        switch(Command)
        {
          case TPM_SIGNAL_HASH_START:
            _rpc__Signal_Hash_Start();
            break;
          case TPM_SIGNAL_HASH_END:
            _rpc__Signal_HashEnd();
            break;
          case TPM_SIGNAL_HASH_DATA:
            OK = ReadVarBytes(s, InputBuffer, &length, MAX_BUFFER);
            if(!OK) return true;
            InBuffer.Buffer = (uint8_t *)InputBuffer;
            InBuffer.BufferSize = length;
            _rpc__Signal_Hash_Data(InBuffer);
            break;
          case TPM_SEND_COMMAND:
            OK = ReadBytes(s, (char*)&locality, 1);
            if(!OK)
            return true;
            OK = ReadVarBytes(s, InputBuffer, &length, MAX_BUFFER);
            if(!OK)
            return true;
            InBuffer.Buffer = (uint8_t *)InputBuffer;
            InBuffer.BufferSize = length;
            OutBuffer.BufferSize = MAX_BUFFER;
            OutBuffer.Buffer = (_OUTPUT_BUFFER)OutputBuffer;
            // record the number of bytes in the command if it is the largest
            // we have seen so far.
            if(InBuffer.BufferSize > CommandResponseSizes.largestCommandSize)
            {
                CommandResponseSizes.largestCommandSize = InBuffer.BufferSize;
                memcpy(&CommandResponseSizes.largestCommand,
                   &InputBuffer[6], sizeof(uint32_t));
            }
            _rpc__Send_Command(locality, InBuffer, &OutBuffer);
            // record the number of bytes in the response if it is the largest
            // we have seen so far.
            if(OutBuffer.BufferSize > CommandResponseSizes.largestResponseSize)
            {
                CommandResponseSizes.largestResponseSize
                = OutBuffer.BufferSize;
                memcpy(&CommandResponseSizes.largestResponse,
                   &OutputBuffer[6], sizeof(uint32_t));
            }
            OK = WriteVarBytes(s,
                       (char*)OutBuffer.Buffer,
                       OutBuffer.BufferSize);
            if(!OK)
            return true;
            break;
          case TPM_REMOTE_HANDSHAKE:
            OK = ReadBytes(s, (char*)&clientVersion, 4);
            if(!OK)
            return true;
            if(clientVersion == 0)
            {
                printf("Unsupported client version (0).\n");
                return true;
            }
            OK &= WriteUINT32(s, ServerVersion);
            OK &= WriteUINT32(s, tpmInRawMode
                      | tpmPlatformAvailable | tpmSupportsPP);
            break;
          case TPM_SET_ALTERNATIVE_RESULT:
            OK = ReadBytes(s, (char*)&result, 4);
            if(!OK)
            return true;
            // Alternative result is not applicable to the simulator.
            break;
          case TPM_SESSION_END:
            // Client signaled end-of-session
            return true;
          case TPM_STOP:
            // Client requested the simulator to exit
            return false;
          default:
            **printf("Unrecognized TPM interface command %d\n", (int)Command);**
            return true;
        }
        OK = WriteUINT32(s, 0);
        if(!OK)
        return true;
    }
}
```

What am doing wrong from client side? meaning, from sample application side? anyone has any idea?

thanks in advance..!

Comment: A `net.Conn` _is_ an `io.ReadWriteCloser`, converting the variable type doesn't change anything in the code, and there usually no reason to convert that anyway. Interfaces are implicitly satisfied. `connection reset by peer` is a TCP error, and has nothing to do with using a `net.Conn` as an `io.ReadWriteCloser`. You need to create a [mre] showing what exactly is happening.

Comment: It looks like you're holding an implicit assumption that the so-called "wire protocols"–that is, exact formats of byte sequences representing "client requests" and "server responses" _are the same_ for both the cases you're dealing with–a special device file and a TCP connection with an emulator. As JimB pointed out, a net.Conn is already an in io.ReadWriteCloser–merely because it has the Read, Write and Close methods (among others). But this is nothing special, really.

Comment: I mean, you should probably first figure out what are wire protocol supported in both cases. There are different approaches to it. One is to study the code which works with the device file and then find a client which is guaranteed to work with the emulator's networked wire protocol (over TCP) and see how they differ. Another way is to [try to ask the emulator's developers](https://sourceforge.net/p/ibmswtpm2/discussion/).

Comment: As to the `connection reset by peer` error–my guess is that it's directly relates to the `Unrecognized TPM interface command 80020000` error reported by the server: the 1st error means your side sent a TCP packet to the remote socket but there was no one to respond (in which case the kernel sends back a TCP packet with the `RST` flag set). Hence I propose the following happens: your code sends a string of bytes which the emulator tries to parse (interpret) according to the format it supports. At same place in the sequence you've sent, it expects to find "a command", so it parses these bytes…

Comment: …and they happen to form an integer value which do not refer to any command known to the emulator. This is a sure sign of the fact the client and the server use differing wire protocols. If the wire protocol understood by the server does not support "simple" framing–which would allow the server to skip _the whole_ message it deems as being incorrect, the server has no other choice except tearing down the connection, as the communication cannot sensibly proceed anyway. I think this is what actually happens.

Comment: @kostix you are exactly correct. I am not familiar with the word wire protocol you are talking about. Can you help me to figure out further. Thanks.

Comment: @Vijay, <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wire_protocol>. Note that for obvious reasons we have to a bend the term a bit when we're talking about working with a device file–because, well, in that case we do not "send" data anywhere but instead write it to a file (and read it back from it). Still, this data must have some _format_ agreed upon by the writers and readers, and in fact since it's a special file, what we write to it is not stored on a filesystem but is actually _sent_ by the kernel to some device or service. That's why the term "wire ptorocol" still applies to this case.

Comment: [1/2] To try to explain what I mean in other words… You have a Go package designed to work with a device file exported by some kernel driver which uses that device file to work with the TPM hardware (I assume). That package necessarily implements some wire protocol implemented by the driver. That's simply because you cannot just "send data": in order to be understood, a sequence of bytes must be orgainzed according to some format, and what is sent/written, and when, must also be agreed upon. These two things combined comprise a wire protocol used to communicate over that special device file.

Comment: [2/2] Now you basically take that Go package and make it speak its wire protocol over a client TCP socket connected to a TPM emulator service. Go allows that, but that's a feature of Go, and it in itself does not mean the wire protocol to be use for communicating with a TPM emulator is the same as the one to communicate with a TPM hardware over a special device file. My guess is that this your assumption is incorrect, and that explains why the emulator seemingly is unable to correctly interpret the data you're shoveling at it.

Comment: @kostix Thanks for your detailed explanation. I got your point. Then I need to check how can we speak to the tpm simulator through the tcp path from the net.Dial. If you have idea, please post that as well here.

Comment: @Vijay, I have already did that in my other comment: «you should probably first figure out what are wire protocol supported in both cases. There are different approaches to it. One is to study the code which works with the device file and then find a client which is guaranteed to work with the emulator's networked wire protocol (over TCP) and see how they differ. Another way is to try to [ask the emulator's developers](https://sourceforge.net/p/ibmswtpm2/discussion/)»–that one. Actually, the most correct way is to read some docs on both protocols, if they exist.

Comment: [The discussion with the devs](https://sourceforge.net/p/ibmswtpm2/discussion/general/thread/10d33e0427/#2827). Next time please do cross-linking yourself ;-) I mean, it would be better if you referred to this question in your post on SF and then post the link to that question here–this makes it way easier for the next guy having your problem to dig deeper.